# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Search with multiple terms

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a method where by I'm able to search in a database for a specific customer(s). At the moment it only takes 1 term, but i'd like to be able to search with multiple terms (for example the customer's account number and their name). Below is my method:

```
public List<AXCustomer> allCustomers(string id)
{
    string[] searchstring = id.Split(' ');
    List<AXCustomer> customer = new List<AXCustomer>();

    // if 3 terms are entered
    if (searchstring.Length > 2)
    {

    }
    // if 2 terms are entered
    else if (searchstring.Length > 1)
    {

    }
    // revert back to default search
    else
    {
        customer = context.AXCustomers.Where(x => x.ACCOUNTNUM.Contains(id) ||
                   x.NAME.Contains(id) || x.ZIPCODE.Contains(id)).ToList();
    }

    return customer;
}
```

As you can see, i've decided to split each term entered (I assume each term will be seperated by a space) but I'm not sure how my LINQ query should be for terms longer than one. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "Account Number and Their Names" ... but if you have an account number, what's the point to search for a name, the `accountId` should point to that name already, why writing it? Maybe you want By Account Number **or** Account Name? is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't know what will be entered or how long it will be, I would suggest doing the following:

```
public List<AXCustomer> allCustomers(string id)
{
    string[] searchstring = id.Split(' ');
    List<List<AXCustomer>> customerlists = new List<List<AXCustomer>>();


    foreach (string word in searchstring)
    {
        customerlists.Add(context.AXCustomers.Where(x => x.ACCOUNTNUM.Contains(word) || x.NAME.Contains(word) || x.ZIPCODE.Contains(word)).ToList());
    }

    //Then you just need to see if you want ANY matches or COMPLETE matches.
    //Throw your results together in a List<AXCustomer> and return it.


    return mycombinedlist;
}
```

- Any matches = throw all lists together, then take the distinct ones.
- Complete matches = you'll have to check for items which occur in all customerlists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is very close. But there is a problem, if I search for say a customer whose name is bob and account number is 123, it'll return all customers whose name is either bob or those whose account number is 123, and not just the customer with the account number 123 and name bob.

Comment: Actually, it will return you a list of all customers whose name, account or zipcode contains 123, and a list of customers whose name, account or zipcode contains bob. if a specific item is mentioned in both lists, then the account, name or ZIP match both 'bob' and '123'. Granted, it could be 'Android123' with accountnumber 'BOBOBOB' but it would still be a valid query as you do not know if the user is querying for account, name or zip.

Comment: You're right, I think I've got what I wanted now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It will work fine. I am using a similar type of query in my project and it seems to work great. Following is the code snippet

```
PagedList.IPagedList<Product> PagedProducts = dbStore.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(query) || p.MetaKeywords.Contains(query)).ToList().ToPagedList(pageIndex, PageSize);
```

BTW, its running on a live server too.

Comment: Yes, this works fine when 1 search term is entered. But if, say I entered an account number followed by a customer name, it'll return 0 results

Comment: right ....that's because neither your id nor your name peroperty will contain something like this `112234 alan`. In such cases, what you will need to do is make token variables for the search term and then check them against id and name

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically `attach` as many conditions as you wish, in the following manner:

```
customer = context.AXCustomers.Where(x => x.ACCOUNTNUM.Contains(id));
customer = customer.Where(Condition 2);
customer = customer.Where(Condition 3);
```

And so on. You have full control over the criteria : just make sure that it resolves to a sequel query.